# Функция "Экспорт"

Tags: mysql

Функция "Экспорт" оперирует с самой базой данных или создает копию?

Comment: Конечно копию. это же данные, а не товар, который исчезает в одном месте при перемещении в другое

Comment: Какая функция "Экспорт" в MySQL? Уточните вопрос